# Traverse selector, by the index number of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to traverse my selector, by the index number of clicked element.

Like this:

**select the *second* child of one div** (#tabby-content)

when **clicking *second* child of other div** (#tabby-labels).

It's solved underneath. But does anyone know how to "clean up the code" and achieve the same thing but in a better way?

```
$("#tabby-labels > .first").click(function() {
        $("#tabby-content > .first").siblings('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $("#tabby-content > .first").addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});

$("#tabby-labels > .second").click(function() {
        $("#tabby-content > .second").siblings('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $("#tabby-content > .second").addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});
    $("#tabby-labels > .third").click(function() {
        $("#tabby-content > .third").siblings('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $("#tabby-content > .third").addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});
    $("#tabby-labels > .fourth").click(function() {
        $("#tabby-content > .fourth").siblings('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $("#tabby-content > .fourth").addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
$("#tabby-label > *").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("#tabby-contents").children('.active').toggleClass("active inactive");
    $("#tabby-contents").children().eq(index).addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
});
```

It assumes that the relevant elements are the only direct children of the two DIVs.